# ld: library not found for -lBoringSSL-GRPC Xcodebuild React Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I have been trying to solve this issue for a week, and I know that there are a lot of similar questions like this already solved, but none of them works for me, I would appreciate any help.

I am building a CI/CD pipeline for my React Native application, and this is the IOS part. I am trying to build from the Bitbucket Pipelines over an SSH connection on a remote Mac.

I am trying to build an Xcode achieve, it works when I do it manually on the remote Mac, from Xcode, but when I run this command I get an error.

```
xcodebuild archive -scheme dst -configuration Release -archivePath ../builds/dst.xcarchive -workspace dst.xcworkspace PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="test-dst-provisioning-release" -UseModernBuildSystem=NO CODE_SIGN_STYLE="Manual" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="Apple Distribution: $(Team code)"
```

This is the error I get:

```
Ld /Users/user931603/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dst-gisgtbcaheaxrqbgvvzueprfinbl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/dst/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/dst.app/dst normal arm64
cd /Users/user931603/build/dst-mobile-prototype/ios
export 
PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/user931603/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.6/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/munki:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin"
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-L/Users/user931603/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dst-gisgtbcaheaxrqbgvvzueprfinbl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/dst/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/BoringSSL-GRPC'
ld: library not found for -lBoringSSL-GRPC
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

For a while I thought that I have a problem with the Library Search Paths

These are my Target - Build settings - Library Search Paths
[image: Target - Build settings - Library Search Paths]

These are my Project - Build settings - Library Search Paths
[image: Project - Build settings - Library Search Paths]

But then it turned out that the achieve works from Xcode, but it doesn't work when I do it remotely on the terminal, so I think there must be an issue with the environment variables or something like this.
I use Cocoapods, there can be a problem with that, the settings are the ones generated automatically by React Native.

I have no clue about this issue, I would appreciate greatly if you could help!

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but with a Flutter app and debug build.  Android version builds & runs fine.  I've confirmed that BoringSSL-GRPC was installed, and suspect something is off in my Xcode project -- my library search path setting for debug is empty, but not entirely sure what it should be set to (I'm an IOS/Xcode rookie).  Just wondering if you ever got this resolved, or if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Yes, I wrote a post about it https://attilaberczik.com/post/ios-bitbucket-cicd-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues too, this is what I did to resolve the issue:

1. Open your project.workspace using Xcode.
2. Go to build settings
3. Select Basic on the Tabs
4. Go to Build Active Architecture only,
   On Debug select yes

[image: My 'Build Active Architecture Only' Screenshot]